# VSCode Nuxt with Typescript breakpoints not hitting

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js

Hi I am using NuxtJs with typescript and VSCode. Everything is working fine but breakpoints are never hitting. debugger is working fine but I need breakpoints to work with my code. I am trying it long time no success.

here is my code

HTML

```
<button @click="breakpointChecker()" />
```

Script

```
breakpointChecker() {
  console.log("Line Before Debugging")
  debugger
  console.log("Debugger will work")
  console.log("Put a breakpoint.It will not work")
  console.log("other breakpoint line. It will not work")
  }
```

Comment: Please provide any source of debugging.

Comment: just call any method on button click and write console. make a break-point and click on button. it'll never hit

Comment: I think it is to be done in configuration i.e sourcemap etc

Comment: Do not write code in the comments (since it is **totally** unreadable) but rather, edit your question.

Comment: I've updated question with code please now take care

Comment: Does this one work: `<button @click="brakpointChecker"></button>` ?

Comment: Actually problem is not with button click. Both not work.

Comment: Actually method is called but no breakpoint is hitting if we use NuxtJs with typescrit

Comment: @kissu Can you please help me?